# Peak to Gaussian function estimation

Tags: r, matlab, math

I have a continuous flow of input data : more than 100.000. There are two values a time and an intensity. The data contains many peaks. Let se part of the data.

[image: This is part of the data that needs to be analized]

Objectives : Search for peaks -> identify them -> calculate area.

Problem : a huge peak (like the one betwen 8.0 and 8.5) could be contain multiple Gaussian (this is just one "normal", there are other type of estimation functions also) peaks for example.

Question : How can I "deconvolute" this peaks in order to measure the area of them.

Example : I want to do something similar like the following matlab code :

[iPeak](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/InteractivePeakFitter.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if "iPeak" is good enough, just port the code to R.  There are a couple packages in R that do thresholded peak finding.  Naturally I forgot their names, being away from my main machine. If I can refresh my brain... possible fits for you:  PROcess, ppc, seewave, Peaks, and the one I like:  pracma.

Note: I found these using the incredibly useful tool `sos`

Comment: I'm working on porting iPeak to R but it has more than 2000 lines so you need to work on it. Not to mention that porting is nice but should be careful each time. I search what you proposed mean time!

Comment: For others who see this post, for porting use this link : [link]http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf

Comment: For more easier use : xcms package!

Comment: You should note that `xcms` is available at bioconductor, but not at the R CRAN package repository.